# Can I connect an address and sign a transaction from nodejs without a browser in Wagmi core

Tags: nodejs, typescript, wagmi

I'm building a `nestjs` backend and I want to execute a **`write`** transaction to the contract as the contract owner,
I couldn't find anyway to connect my address and sign the transaction programmatically to execute a write task without
needing a browser.

Answer (score 1):

- Install `ethers` lib:

`npm install ethers`

- Send transaction:

```
// connect provider 
const provider = new ethers.ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(YOUR_RPC_URL);

// connect your signer
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

// send your transaction
const tx = signer.sendTransaction({
   to: "ricmoo.firefly.eth",
   value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is feasible,  instantiating a wallet and signing the transactions.

```
    const provider = "YOUR PROVIDER" // rpc normally

    // PRIVATE KEY .env file
    const privKeyDEPLOYER = process.env['DEPLOYER_KEY'] as BytesLike;

    // wallet creation
    const deployer_wallet = new Wallet(privKeyDEPLOYER);

    // deployer creation
    const deployer = await deployer_wallet.connect(provider);
```

Now with you deployer you can sign transacrions`enter code here`

Remember to `.gitignore` your `.env` file